# Lua, insert value from loop into new table

Tags: lua

I am trying to figure out how to loop through a LUA table and take the results of a field and enter them into a new table. In the sample code below I would like to get the phone value from each record and insert it into the new table phoneNumbers. I have tried several ways of doing this and basically I keep getting a table with no data.

I am not sure what I am missing, but I feel it has something to do with value.phone. Any help is appreciated!

```
local phoneNumbers = {}
local people = {
   {
       name = "Fred",
       address = "16 Long Street",
       phone = "123456"
   },
   {
       name = "Wilma",
       address = "16 Long Street",
       phone = "123456"
   },
   {
       name = "Barney",
       address = "17 Long Street",
       phone = "123457"
   }
}
        for index,data in ipairs(people) do
            for key, value in pairs(data) do
        --print('\t', key, value)
        table.insert(phoneNumbers, 1, value.phone)
        --phoneNumbers[1] = value.phone
      end
    end
```

Comment: You're code looks like you're overthinking it. Take out the inner `for` statement. The info you want is in `data.phone`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comment, you can do:

```
for i = 1, #people do
    phoneNumbers[i] = people[i].phone
end

-- test to see the result
for i = 1, #phoneNumbers do
    print(phoneNumbers[i])
end
```

Or this also works:

```
for k, v in pairs(people) do
    phoneNumbers[k] = v.phone
end

-- test to see the result
for k, v in pairs(phoneNumbers) do
    print(k, v)
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your solutions. I prefer the second solution. One question...why the k in phoneNumers[k]?

Comment: you can name it whatever you like, but for me k, v (key, value pairs) are more readable.

Comment: oh I misunderstood your question, I put k to avoid assigning an index (i) and doing i = i + 1

Comment: OK. So the K just assigns the index of the original table to the new table? Am I understanding that correctly? I would have just tried phoneNumbers[]. Would that have not worked?

Comment: no that wouldn't have worked, you need an index, see the first example, unless you use table.insert...